# How can I do a left join but with two clauses

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel-4, query-builder

I have two tables called `listings` and `listings_queue`.  They are identical in structure.  The idea is that records get put in the queue, stuff is done to them, and then they're moved to `listings`.

I want to run a query that pulls any record that exists in `listings` but not in `listings_queue`.  The criteria for not existing is that it doesn't have the field mls_listing_id and mls_id that match any in `listings_queue`.

In plain english, "Give me any record in `listings` that doesn't have a record in `listings_queue` with the same mls_id AND mls_listing_id.

I've tried doing where clauses but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way you can do this with a `where` clause:

```
select l.*
from listings l
where not exists (select 1
                  from listings_queue lq
                  where lq.mis_id = l.mis_id and lq.mis_listing_id = l.mis_listing_id
                 );
```

You can also do this as a left outer join:

```
select l.*
from listings l left outer join
     listings_queue lq
     on lq.mis_id = l.mis_id and lq.mis_listing_id = l.mis_listing_id
where lq.mis_id is null;
```

This could produce duplicates if the `listings_queue` table has multiple matches.